# i want to repeat an image depending on the number in a specific cell and this should only be in a specific cell range eg(B15:G290)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this is the formula i came up with

```
=ArrayFormula(IMAGE(SPLIT(REPT("https://photos.fife.usercontent.google.com/pw/AP1GczP1TsGyvefDEpaJEaQnYpKkQh_q64teHGEHmriwlfWcxjRnrNc4Tm71=w217-h217-s-no-gm?authuser=0"&"|",F11),"|")))
```

it's going over the cell range

this is what i tried

[image: this is what i tried]

i need it to be in the cell range provided.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think REPT( formula is working with images.
But what you can do is substitute your image by an emoji Or convert it into an emoji format, that will work.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat an image across a **N×M** range you can use the [`MAKEARRAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=MAKEARRAY(N,M,LAMBDA(_,__,IMAGE("<image_url>")))
```

For example:

```cpp
=MAKEARRAY(A1,1,LAMBDA(_,__,IMAGE("https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/sheets_2020q4_48dp.png")))
```

[image]